# How do I multiply a long integer with different numbers in C program?

Tags: c, arrays

I am very new to C programming and I am writing a program which takes a number which is suppose to be 9 digits long. After this I multiply each digit with either 1 or 2. I am using arrays to ask user to enter their numbers. I would like to know if there is a way to multiply those 9 numbers with different numbers as one integer instead of using arrays? Here is my code with arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int sin_num[9];
    int num1;
    int num2, num11, num12;
    int num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10;



    for(num1=0; num1<9; num1++) {
            printf("Enter your SIN number one by one:");
            scanf("%d", &sin_num[num1]);
    }


    num2 = sin_num[0] * 1;
    num3 = sin_num[1] * 2;
    num4 = sin_num[2] * 1;
    num5 = sin_num[3] * 2;
    num6 = sin_num[4] * 1;
    num7 = sin_num[5] * 2;
    num8 = sin_num[6] * 1;
    num9 = sin_num[7] * 2;
    num10 = sin_num[8] * 1;
```

Right now I am doing this:
element 1 * 1
element 2 * 2
element 3 * 1
But how can I do, lets say if I enter 123456789 multiply with different numbers:

```
123456789
121212121
```

Comment: Why an array?   Why can't you just multiply the user's number with ... huh?  What does it mean "multiply each digit with 1 or 2"?

Comment: What happens when the multiplication carries? (Like if you have the digit 8 being multiplied by 2).

Comment: I can't figure out how to multiply each number that a user enters with different numbers. I mean if I enter 123456789 that is considered 1 number, so I can't multiply each number with different digits. I can't do 1*1 or 4*2.

Comment: When a number is multiplied the program show its multiplied value. If 5*2 it will show 10.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) for checksumming (among other things) credit card and Canadian Social Insurance numbers. If I'm correct, there is a "carry" of a sort, but it's not like any normal carry (you double specific digits numerically, and if the result is two digits, you sum those digits).

Comment: You are correct. I have completed this program, but it took a while to finish with array, so I want to know if there is another way without arrays!

Comment: The code does not implement any limitation on the magnitude of the integer numbers entered.  So a user could enter: 999999999 for the first number and similar for the other 8 numbers.   Suggest you modify the code to input a single digit at each input " %c", check that the digit is in the range '0'...'9', reject digits outside that range, then convert each digit to int by int value[x] = digit[x] - '0';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I couldn't much understand what you were asking. Anyways hope this is what you are looking for.....

```
 #include<stdio.h>


 int main()
 {

   long int nine_digit_num;
   int step=100000000;
   int digit,input_num,i;

   printf("Enter 9 digit number:\n");
   scanf("%ld",&nine_digit_num);


   for(i=1;i<=9;i++)
   {  
     printf("Enter a number to multiply with the %d digit:\n",i);
     scanf("%d",&input_num);
     digit=nine_digit_num/step; // this and the next step are used to
     digit=digit%10;            // obtain the individual digits.
     printf("%d*%d=%d\n",digit,input_num,digit*input_num);
     step=step/10;
  }
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are Luhn algorithm solutions already written that you could reference, but I'm going to invent my own right now just to have a walkthrough.

Since your input is only 9 digits, it will fit in a plain 32 bit variable. I'll use `unsigned` on the assumption it's 32 bits or bigger, but for production code, you'd likely want to use `inttypes.h` `uint32_t` and associated `scanf` macros.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    unsigned sin_num, checksum, digit;
    int i;

    printf("Enter your SIN as a 9 digit number using only digits:\n");
    if (scanf(" %9u", &sin_num) < 1) ... do error handling or just exit ...

    for (i = 0; sin_num; ++i) {
        digit = sin_num % 10;
        sin_num /= 10;
        if (i & 1) { // Double odd digits (might have this backwards; check me for your case
            digit *= 2;
            if (digit >= 10) digit = digit % 10 + digit / 10; // Luhn carry is strange
        }
        checksum += digit;
    }

    ... do whatever else you need to do ...
```

It's not a single mathematical operation because Luhn's carry is too weird for magic number tricks, but it's still much more straightforward than a bunch of single digit `scanf` calls and array storage.

Comment: the OP did not state that he is trying to implement a Luhn algorithm.  (although it sort of looks like it)   So some of this answer may be way 'off base' if the OP is not trying to implement a Luhn algorithm

Comment: He did. Read the comments on the question.